# Problem in generating summpy data set for Telcom

Tags: python-3.x

Require your assistance for helping me solve this issue:

Problem Statement - I need to create a dummpy dataset for Telecom domain for past 6 months. I used random number to generate Date and Time and used the below code to create in Pandas. Generating additional columns in pandas for this dataset I am able to do but stuck with random date and time :

> test = pd.DataFrame({ 
>                'Date':pd.date_range(start='2016-09-20',freq='1h', periods=10000)
>              })

This creates a periodic data and time entry with exact difference of one hr. Sample output is shown:

Date
0    2016-09-20 00:00:00
1    2016-09-20 01:00:00
2    2016-09-20 02:00:00
3    2016-09-20 03:00:00
4    2016-09-20 04:00:00

But I need specific thing for creation of dataset:

a) Need more random date and time entries for timestamp between 8 am to 8 pm as each entry represents a call entry.
b) Need less entries for random date and time entries for timestamp between 8pm to 8am as less people call in the night.
c) Need less random date and time entries for weekends( Saturdays  & Sundays)

Can anybody please help me in providing an approach and solution for this ? These conditions are required as need to perform ML modelling on this dataset and with these conditions this dumpy dataset will be more realistic towards telecom sector.